# An application of Hewitt-Savage $0-1$ law. Some doubts/observations

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, proof-explanation, brownian-motion, limsup-and-liminf

*I quote Kuo (2006)*
Keeping in mind the Hewitt-Savage $0-1$ law for exchangeable events, that is:

> If $E$ is an exchangeable event for an independent identically distributed sequence, than $\mathbb{P}(E)$ is either $0$ or $1$.

I am trying to understand the proof of the following proposition:

> **Proposition.** Let $\{B(t):t\ge0\}$ be a standard Brownian motion. Almost surely,
> $$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{B(n)}{\sqrt{n}}=+\infty\hspace{0.5cm}\text{ and }\hspace{0.5cm}\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{B(n)}{\sqrt{n}}=-\infty$$

Herebelow, I write the proof and - in $\color{red}{\text{ bold red }}$ - my doubts/observations:

> **Proof of proposition.** By Fatou's lemma:
> $$\mathbb{P}\{B(n)>c\sqrt{n}\text{ infinitely often}\}=\mathbb{P}\{\limsup_{n\to\infty}(B(n)>c\sqrt{n})\}\ge\limsup_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}\{B(n)>c\sqrt{n}\}$$
> By the scaling property, the expression in $\limsup$ equals $\mathbb{P}\{B(1)>c\}$, which is positive. $\color{red}{\text{($1.$ Why is it positive? Couldn't it be $0$?)}}$
> Let $X_n=B(n)-B(n-1)$ and note that $$\{B_n>c\sqrt{n}\text{ infinitely often}\}=\{\sum_{j=1}^n X_j>c\sqrt{n}\text{ infinitely often}\}$$
> is an exchangeable event. 
> $\color{red}{\text{($2.$ Why is that an exchangeable event (by def.))?}}$
> Hence, the Hewitt-Savage $0-1$ law gives that, with probability one, $B(n)>c\sqrt{n}$.
> $\color{red}{\text{($3.$ As stated above, Hewitt-Savage $0-1$ law establishes that probability associated to}}$ $\color{red}{\text{ an exchangeable event is either $0$ or $1$. So, why could we say with certainty that }}$ $\color{red}{\text{$\mathbb{P}(B(n)>c\sqrt{n}$ infinitely often)$=1$ and not that $\mathbb{P}(B(n)>c\sqrt{n}$ infinitely often)$=0$?)}}$
> Taking the intersection over all positive integers $c$ gives the first part of the proposition and the second part is proven analogously.
> $\color{red}{\text{($4.$What is exactly meant here? One shall take intersection of which events? How can}}$ $\color{red}{\text{this allow to pass from}}$ $\color{red}{\text{$\mathbb{P}(B(n)>c\sqrt{n}\text{ infinitely often})=1$ to $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{B(n)}{\sqrt{n}}=+\infty$?)}}$

Comment: 1. $B(1)$ is normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $1$.  So $\mathbb{P}\{B(1)>c\}$ is positive.

Comment: Got it just thinking about standard normal Cumulative Distribution Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\{\limsup B_n/\sqrt{n}\ge c\}\supseteq \{B_n/\sqrt{n}> c\text{ i.o.}\}\equiv A$ and
$$
\{\limsup B_n/\sqrt{n}=+\infty\}=\bigcap_{c\in \mathbb{N}}\{\limsup B_n/\sqrt{n}\ge c\}.
$$
If the probability of each event in the intersection is $1$, then the probability of the intersection of these events is also $1$. Since $\mathsf{P}(A)\in \{0,1\}$ ($\because A$ is an exchangeable event) and $\mathsf{P}(A)\ge \mathsf{P}(B_1>c)>0$, the result follows.

---

**Exchangeable event**. An event $E\in \sigma(X_1,X_2,\ldots)$ is exchangeable iff there exists $B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$ s.t. for each $n\ge 1$ and any permutation $\pi_n$ of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$,
$$
E=\{(X_1,\ldots,X_n,X_{n+1}\ldots)\in B\}=\{(X_{\pi_n(1)},\ldots,X_{\pi_n(n)},X_{n+1},\ldots)\in B\}.
$$

In your case $X_n:=B_{n}-B_{n-1}$, $n\ge 1$ with $B_0\equiv 0$, and $E=\{\sum_{i= 1}^n X_i> c\sqrt{n}\text{ i.o.}\}$.

Comment: First of all, thank you a lot. Just some questions: $$1.\text{Why do you say }\{\limsup B_n/\sqrt{n}\ge c\}\color{red}{\supseteq} \{B_n/\sqrt{n}\ge c\text{ i.o.}\}\equiv A\text{ and not }$$ $$\{\limsup B_n/\sqrt{n}\ge c\}\color{red}{=}\{B_n/\sqrt{n}\ge c\text{ i.o.}\}\equiv A? \text{(see for ex. Resnick, Lemma 1.3)}$$ $$2.\text{ Why }\mathsf{P}(A)\ge \mathsf{P}(B_1>c)\text{? Why can be sure of that?}$$ $$3. \text{So, }E=\{\sum_{i= 1}^n X_i\ge c\sqrt{n}\text{ i.o.}\}\text{ is exchangeable since (for ex.) }$$$$\{X_1+X_2+\ldots+X_n>\ldots\}=\{X_2+X_1+\ldots+X_n>\ldots\}\text{?}$$ @d.k.o.

Comment: @Strictly_increasing (1) Follows from the definition of $\limsup$ for real sequences, that is, if $x_n> c$ i.o., then $\limsup x_n \ge c$. The other way around is false; take, for example, an increasing sequence converging to $c$. In this case, $\limsup x_n=\sup x_n=c$ but $x_n<c$ for each $n$.

Comment: (2) Follows, for example, from the reverse [Fatou lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma#Reverse_Fatou_lemma) and the scaling property.

Comment: So, as to point $(1)$, the definition on Resnick ($A_n$ is a sequence of subsets of $\Omega$):
"$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}A_n=\{\omega:\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}1_{A_n}\omega=\infty\}=\{\omega:\omega\in A_{n_k}, k=1,2,\ldots\}$$ for some subsequence $n_k$ depending on $\omega$. Consequently, we write $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n=[A_n\text{ i.o.}]$$"
is wrong, isn't it? @d.k.o.

Comment: It's the definition of the $\limsup$ of a sequence of events...

Comment: OK, while in the above case we are talking about the definition of the $\limsup$ of a random variable (namely, $B(t)$). Is that the point?

Comment: (3) The event $E$ doesn't depend on what happens with the first $n$ partial sums $S_n:=\sum_{i\le n}X_i$. An $\omega$ belongs to $E$ if $S_{n+1}(\omega)/\sqrt{n+1},S_{n+2}(\omega)/\sqrt{n+2},\ldots$ exceed $c$ infinitely often.